# Linq to xml : can't load all elements

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

i'm trying to load some elements from a xml file.
but it XDocument.Load seems not treating xml file properly in this case, the method returns the content of the xml file as one node.

here is my xml content:

```
<processes>
 <process>winamp</process>
 <process>Acrobat</process>
 <process>WinRAR</process>
</processes>
```

and the code that reads the file:

```
 XDocument loaded = XDocument.Load("/process_list.xml");
   var x = from a in loaded.Descendants("processes")
            select a.Element("process");
    foreach (var t in x)
    {
            Console.WritleLine(t.Value.ToString());
    }
```

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code selects the first `process` element from each `processes` element in the document -- of which there is only one.

To select all `process` elements in the document, try this:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("process_list.xml");

foreach (var element in doc.Descendants("process"))
{
    Console.WritleLine(element.Value);
}
```

Comment: so how can i make it select all the "process" elements.